# Parametrizing a static webdriver fixture and a generator in Pytest?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, generator, fixtures

I'm building an automation test for finding any possible dead links in a WP plugin. To this end, I have two helper functions.

The first spins up a Selenium webdriver:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def setup():
    d = webdriver.Firefox()
    site = os.getenv('TestSite')
    d.get(site)
    login = d.find_element_by_id('user_login')
    d.implicitly_wait(5)
    user, pw = os.getenv('TestUser'), os.getenv('TestPw')
    d.find_element(By.ID, 'user_login').send_keys(user)
    d.find_element(By.ID, 'user_pass').send_keys(pw)
    d.find_element(By.ID, 'wp-submit').click()
    yield d, site
    d.quit()
```

The second reads in a JSON file, picking out each page in the file then yielding it to the third function:

```py
def page_generator() -> Iterator[Dict[str, Any]]:
    try:
        json_path = '../linkList.json'
        doc = open(json_path)
        body = json.loads(doc.read())
        doc.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f'Did not find a file at {json_path}')
        exit(1)
    for page in body['pages']:
        yield page
```

The third function is the meat and potatoes of the test, running through the page and looking for each link. My goal is to parametrize each page, with my function header presently looking like...

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('spin_up, page', [(setup, p) for p in page_generator()])
def test_links(spin_up, page):
    driver, site = spin_up
    # Do all the things
```

Unfortunately, running this results in `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object`. Is the only option to stick `yield d, site` inside some sort of loop to turn the function into an iterable, or is there a way to tell `test_links` to iteratively pull the same setup function as its `spin_up` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to do what you want, and that's to specify the `setup` fixture directly as an argument to `test_links`.  Note that `pytest` is smart enough to figure out that the `setup` argument refers to a fixture while the `page` argument refers to a parametrization:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('page', page_generator())
def test_links(setup, page):
    driver, site = setup
```

You might also take a look at [`parametrize_from_file`](https://parametrize-from-file.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  This is a package I wrote to help with loading test cases from JSON/YAML/TOML files.  It basically does the same thing as your `page_generator()` function, but more succinctly (and more generally).